# Is velvet uncountable？

Tags: word-usage, articles

I see a sentence in my book:

> Diamond necklaces and rings had been beautifully arranged on a background of black velvet.

Why not say: **of a black velvet**？

Comment: It's uncountable (referring to a substance/matter, thus "of black velvet"), but you might describe a particular instance of that substance (as in "a lovely/beautiful black velvet"). Similarly, "We looked up at the sky." vs "There was a bright blue sky."

Answer (score 2):

Like many words, *velvet* can be used as either a count or non-count noun. When used as a count noun, the meaning is of specific types of the material in question.

For example, "the sands" (*sand* used as a count noun) indicates several types of sand (maybe coarse sand from one a beach and fine sand from the desert) considered together.

Or, "a high-strength glue" indicates one of the many kinds of glue available; in this case a particularly strong one.

In your example, the fact that there are other kinds of velvet in the world isn't relevant to the writer's intended meaning, so they use *velvet* as a non-count noun and simply tell you the background was made of velvet, without leading you to consider that the velvet was one kind of velvet chosen from among many different kinds of velvet that might exist.

Comment: Fabric is treated as uncountable, like a substance. The countable form would be _a piece_ or _a length of black velvet_.

Comment: Her dress was in a lovely black velvet?

Comment: @KateBunting, but I can also say "there are many fine fabrics available at the fabric store", or,  "the dress was made from a particularly fine fabric".